# Page_Load executing Twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know that this question has been asked before, but none of the remedies seem to be my solution.

I have an `aspx` page and a code behind with a `Page_Load` routine. My routine writes a record to a SQL table to capture the user's credentials.

The Page_Load has a `!IsPostBack` check, aspx has `AutoEventWireup="True"`, and I have no `img` or any other element that would cause an `AutoPostback` to my knowledge. Still `Page_Load` is called twice.

Here is my `.aspx` page and the code behind. I am hoping someone can help.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="feedback.aspx.cs" Inherits="MEAU.Web.Components.SupportCenter.feedback" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Security.Accounts" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/SupportCenter/design/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/SupportCenter/design/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/SupportCenter/design/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/SupportCenter/design/js/jquery.accordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/SupportCenter/design/js/jquery.pngFix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/SupportCenter/design/js/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/SupportCenter/design/js/jquery-tmpl.js"></script>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <style>
        p.titlefont
        {
            font-family: "Arial" , Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
            font-size:"12px";
        }
    </style>
    <title>Feedback</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Init() {
            var obj = window.dialogArguments;
            var url = document.getElementById("url1");
            var login = document.getElementById("login");
        }

        function getRadioValue(theRadioGroup) {
            for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup).length; i++) {
                if (document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup)[i].checked) {
                    return document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup)[i].id;
                }
            }
        }

        function WriteToFile(sText) {

            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var fo = fso.OpenTextFile('c:\\\inetput\\wwwwroot\LogFile.txt', 8, true, 0); // 8=append, true=create if not exist, 0 = ASCII
            fo.WriteLine();
            fo.Write(sText);

            fo.Close();
        }     
    </script>
</head>
<!--<body onload="javascript:Init();"> -->
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p class="titlefont">
            <asp:Literal ID="quest" Text="Did this resolve your issue?" runat="server" />
            <br />

            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="yes" runat="server" Text="Yes" Checked="true"
                Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" /><br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="no" runat="server" Text="No" Font-Names="Arial"
                Font-Size="12px" /><br />
            <asp:Literal ID="lit" Text="Please select at least one answer" runat="server" Visible="false"/><br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="scall" runat="server" Text="Did this prevent a Service Call?" Visible="false" Font-Names="Arial"
                Font-Size="12px" /><br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="parts" runat="server" Text="Did this prevent a Parts Shipment?" Visible="false"
                Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" /><br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="wrnt" runat="server" Text="Is this under Warranty?" Font-Names="Arial" Visible="false"
                Font-Size="12px" /><br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="none" runat="server" Text="None of the above" Font-Names="Arial" Visible="false"
                Font-Size="12px" /><br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="run" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="Run_Write" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial"
                Font-Size="12px" /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="cancel" Text=" CANCEL " OnClick="Cancel_btn" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial"
                Font-Size="12px" />
        </p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    login = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Current.Profile.Email;
    myurl = Request.QueryString["value"];

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Write a record and capture the User's credententials, even if they do not take an action
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetConnectionString("feedback"));
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_fb", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", myurl);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@response", "No");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noResponse", "Yes");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serviceCall", "No");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partsShipment", "No");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@warranty", "No");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cancel", "No");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@none", "No");

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error on file update" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest putting a break-point on your Page_Load event and when the break-point is hit, then look for the value in  `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]`, which represents the unique ID of the control that caused the postback.

Comment: forgive me, but I don't know how to do that. I have a break point for each line, but where do I find Request.Form?

Comment: some other research I have done, keeps eluding to this line of code needing to be removed, but I cannot find this either:                                                        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);

Comment: When you are at a break-point, go to the Debug menu in Visual Studio and then Windows, from there choose the Immediate Window. Upon the Immediate Window being available, then type in `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` and hit enter; the initial page load will have a value of NULL, because no control initiated a postback, because it is not a postback, but subsequent postbacks will have a value for `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]`.

Comment: so, I ran the debug, and Request.Form["_EVENTTARGET"] is null and it is executed twice.

Comment: Does it get to the end of `Page_Load` without error on the first page load?

Comment: yes, there are no errors

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32520/discussion-between-karl-and-paul-t-rykiel)

Comment: Try setting breakpoints in you JavaScript. Maybe one of the functions causes postback?...